# How can I change the key names in celery

Tags: python, redis, celery

After the finishing a task, celery writes it in to redis. However, the key of the entry is determined by celery itself(I think it is the task id). I want to give specific names because that's how other services know their place.

In my code there is one producer that creates the tasks and many workers.
Right now I use tasks_name.get() after all tasks get completed and create new redis entries with my naming convention.
But that is that seems so unnecessary and slow. Celery should just use my convention.

I am thinking about renaming them but if this is feasible. How can I receive ids from producer.
Maybe some custom RedisBackend class but that is too deep.

Comment: Shouldn't other services just know the task ID instead, so they can use the Celery API to request and decode the result value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the task a custom ID using `task_id` parameter when submitting the task. It's supported by [`apply`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply) and [`apply_async`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async) methods of Celery task and [`send_task`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.send_task) method of Celery class.

Comment: Still adds the prefix but I think this is good enough. Thanks.